# php name and surname validation

Tags: php, validation

Good afternoon,

I'm writing a web site and I would like to control name and surname in a form.
Most of the users are Czech (for example, Jindřiška Nováková), so I need to control their names with UTF-8 encoding. I wrote a PHP code which is supposed to control person's name and surname:

```
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
if(!mb_check_encoding($_POST['name']))
{
   echo '<div class="alert">The surname format is wrong!</div>';
}
if(!mb_check_encoding($_POST['surname']))
{
   echo '<div class="alert">The name format is wrong!</div>';
}
    }
```

But this code is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of checking if encoding is in fact UTF-8 you could force this encoding. 

Here is helpfull lib: https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

As for name and surname validation, only thing that you should check in most cases is if string is alphanumeric.

Comment: Do the validation on clients using JavaScript.

Comment: you can have a name like this `Novakova` i mean it doesn't contains `à ù ...` or every name must contains a special characters ?

Comment: Yes it has, or it will be very offensive for a person.

Answer (score -1):

another option it's to use javascript.

Regards
Claudio

Comment: I use javascrypt but I need to use PHP as well just in case.